# Hide div if it contains img with src that contains x?

Tags: javascript

If a div with `id=module-120` contains an image with a source that contains: `completion-auto-y` I want to hide that parent div `module-120`.

This is as far as I got but it's not working.

```
if (document.getElementById('#module-120')) {

    function verifyImageURL(url, callBack) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = url;
        img.onload = function () {
            callBack(true);
        };
        img.onerror = function () {
            callBack(false);
        };
    }

    var url = "completion-auto-y";
    verifyImageURL(url, function (imageExists) {
        if (imageExists === true) {
             document.getElementById('#module-120').style.display="none";
        } 
    });     
}
```

I think the problem is within the `var url = "completion-auto-y"`. Does someone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: This is all very confusing, your talking a bout a div, but I see no div, your talking about `var url` but I see no `var url`. This seems to be a script that test if you can download an image, not if an image exists in a div? Basically I'm confused as to what you want here?

Answer (score 4):

Well first, let's be clear that you should only ever have one element with a given `id`, so you'd only need to ever hide, at most, one element.

So, the solution is to use [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) along with the appropriate CSS selector to get a reference to the image that has a parent that should be hidden. Then hide the parent element.

```js
// Get the image that matches the criteria
let match = document.querySelector("div[id='module-120'] img[src*='completion-auto-y']");

match.parentNode.classList.add("hidden");  // Hide the parent element
```

```css
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<div id="module-120">
 <img src="completion-auto-x">
 I should not be hidden
</div>
<div id="module-120">
 <img src="completion-auto-y">
 I should be hidden
</div>
```